# Why python superclass constructor call is failing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help me in fixing the error? Why I am not able to call superclass constructor from a child-class constructor?

Parent Class:

```
11:23 $ more Restaurant.py
class Restaurant:

 def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
  self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name;
  self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type;
```

Child Class:

```
✔ ~/Documents/python
11:23 $ more IceCreamStand.py
from Restaurant import Restaurant
class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):

def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type, flavor):
 super().__init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
 self.flavor = flavor

✔ ~/Documents/python
11:23 $ more testInherit.py
from IceCreamStand import IceCreamStand as ic

ic1 = ic('b','Indian','Strawberry')
ic2 = ic('a','Italian','Butterscotch')
rest1 = Restaurant('Rooh','All')

✔ ~/Documents/python
```

Test class to create objects:

```
11:23 $ python3 testInherit.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testInherit.py", line 3, in <module>
    ic1 = ic('b','Indian','Strawberry')
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
✘-1 ~/Documents/python
```

Comment: you are passing `self` also in `super().__init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type)` remove it, Ans `__init__` is not a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Remove self from `super.__init()__` call. The `__init__()` method forwards the parameters to the constructor of its base (Restaurant) class using the super() function which includes the **self** variable.

```
from Restaurant import Restaurant

class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type, flavor):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type) # <== updated
        self.flavor = flavor
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, in actual method or constructor, calls self should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue was the indentation of the method and constructor in the class in IceCreamStand.py. After that it started working.